# Noise Words SQL SERVER 2005 BackSlash

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

How do I make SQL SERVER 2005 to ignore the backslash in the following search:

```
select [description] from MyTable where contains([description], '3/4 and bear')
```

It is blowing off on "/"!

Comment: That's a forward slash, not a backslash.

Comment: looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319730/escaping-bracket-in-a-contains-clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using '"3/4 and bear'"

Answer (score 0):

Try this


**select [description] from MyTable 


where [description] LIKE '%3/4 and bear%'**

Comment: Thanks but I really need to use Full Text Search!